# C Read in bash : stdin and stdout

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, buffer

I have a simple C program with the read function and I don't understand the output.

```
//code1.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{

    int r;
    char c; // In C, char values are stored in 1 byte

    r = read ( 0, &c, 1);

    // DOC:
    //ssize_t read (int filedes, void *buffer, size_t size)
    //The read function reads up to size bytes from the file with descriptor filedes, storing the results in the buffer.
    //The return value is the number of bytes actually read.

    // Here:
    // filedes is 0, which is stdin from <stdio.h>
    // *buffer is &c : address in memory of char c
    // size is 1 meaning it will read only 1 byte

    printf ("r = %d\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot of program executio]

I ran this program 2 times as showed above and typed "a" for the first try and "aecho hi" for the second try.

How I try to explain the results:

1. When `read` is called it sees that stdin is closed and opens it (from my point of view, why? It should just read it. I don't know why it opens it).
2. I type "aecho hi" in the bash and press enter.
3. `read` has priority to process stdin and reads the first byte of "aecho hi" : "a".
4. I get the confirmation that `read` has processed 1 byte with the printf.
5. a.out has finished and is terminated.
6. Somehow the remaining data in stdin is processed in bash (the father of my program) and goes to stdout which executes it and for some reason the first byte has been deleted by `read`.

This is all hypothetical and very blurry. Any help understanding what is happening would be very welcome.

Comment: `stdin` is opened when the program starts, not just when `read()` is called. The rest of your explanations is correct.

Comment: `stdin` isn't a "*process*", but a stream, as `stdout` is as well.

Comment: "*goes to stdout*" not really, the shell (bash here) echoes what it read via `stdin` to `stdout`, then executes what it read (`echo hi`) and prints/writes the result (`hi`) to `stdout`.

Comment: @alk
It's the read function that gets me a blinking cursor in bash waiting for me to populate that input. Why does it do that and not just see that stdin is empty ?

Comment: `read()` is *specified* to block and wait for as many input as it was told (1 byte in your case) or until the input stream explicitly gets told: "no more input", which you could do from the console (under UNIX) by pressing Ctrl-D. The blinking cursor is by the shell.

Comment: It might be educational for you to replace the `read()` call with `getchar()` and try the `aecho hi` input again.  You should be able to explain the difference (hint: the standard I/O package does buffered I/O; `read()` does not).  You should also be able to explain the extra prompt you get when you try the `a` input with your original code (and that you don't get with the `getchar()` variant).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have a very close question. AFAIK, as we type some `echo hi` at the terminal emulator the line discipline immediately echoes it back so we can see this line at the terminal window. Shell itself does not do echo. The same takes place in the OP's example: we're seeing `aecho hi` as typing the symbols. But why then there is the `echo hi` line just after `./a.out` completes? My humble guess is if shell reads out a command with a trailing `<enter>` (shell gets `echo hi<enter>` to read out) it does echo, otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type at your terminal emulator, it writes your keystrokes to a "file", in this case an in-memory buffer that, thanks to the file system, looks just like any other file that might be on disk.

Every process inherits 3 open file handles from its parent. We are interested in one of them here, standard input. The program executed by the terminal emulator (here, `bash`), is given as its standard input the in-memory buffer described in the first paragraph.

`a.out`, when run by `bash`, *also* receives this same file as *its* standard input. Keep this in mind: `bash` and `a.out` are reading from the same, already-opened file.

After you run `a.out`, its `read` blocks, because its standard input is empty. When you type `aecho hi<enter>`, the terminal writes these characters to the buffer (`<enter>` becoming a single linefeed character). `a.out` only requests *one* character, so it gets `a` and leaves the rest of the characters in the file. (Or more precisely, the file pointer is still pointing at the `e` after `a` is read.)

After `a.out` completes, `bash` tries to read from the same file. Normally, the file is empty (i.e., the file pointer is at the end of the file), so `bash` blocks waiting for another command. In this case, though, there is input available already: `echo hi\n`. `bash` reads this now the same as if you had typed it *after* `a.out` completed.

Comment: AFAIK, when we type `echo hi` at the terminal emulator, the line discipline echoes this line back so wee can see it at the terminal window. The same takes place in the OP's example when we see `aecho hi` immediately after it has been typed in. But why there is the `echo hi` line, which appears after `./a.out` completes? Who makes this echo?

Comment: It's the portion of the standard input that `a.out` did not consume; the shell (or more specifically, the Readline library) causes the input buffer to be displayed. (The shell inherits its standard input from the terminal, and `a.out` from the shell; whatever `a.out` does not read, the shell does, just as if OP had typed it after `a.out` exited.)

Comment: But when we just type at the terminal emulator some `echo hi<enter>` we do not see this line twice, only once - that which is echoed back by the line discipline (to my knowledge). In this case the shell in the same way does read from the standard input, however. In the OP's example this line appears twice (`aecho hi` and `echo hi`). So what's the difference?

Comment: The terminal echos `aecho hi` as the user types. After `a.out` exits, the shell can check its standard input, and if a read succeeds, it can echo that after it displays the prompt and before waiting (if necessary) for further input.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/working-stdin-and-stdout). As alk suggests stdin and stdout are already open with the program. Now you have to understand, once you type:

```
aecho hi
```

and hit return the `stdin` buffer is filled with all those letters (and space) - and will continue to be as long as you don't flush it. When the program exits, the stdin buffer is still full, and your terminal automatically handles a write into `stdin` by echoing it to `stdout` - this is what you're seeing at the end - your shell reading `stdin`.

Now as you point out, your code "presses return" for you so to speak - in the first execution adding an empty shell line, and in the second executing `echo hi`. But you must remember, **you pressed return**, so "\n" is in the buffer! To be explicit, you in fact typed:

```
aecho hi\n
```

Once your program exits the shell reads the remaining characters in the buffer, **including the return**, and that's what you see!

Comment: But why has read flushed the "a" from "aecho hi" ?
And in the first execution the buffer is empty ( assuming read flushed the "a" ). Yet it still executes an empty command.

Comment: I don't follow - in the first execution you typed 'a'. That filled the buffer with 'a', which read than flushes (yes read removes what it reads). This is the way read works (like most things that read, you want the next call to read the next letter, not the same one -scanf, get, etc...). Then there is still the "\n" - Return! I'll edit my answer I forgot it.

Comment: About the "\n" : I am "forced" to press enter to say i finished populating that input, if I were able to bypass  that the program would just put the rest of the text in stdout which i would be able to edit in bash ( as it didn't execute yet with an \n ). How do i do that ?

Comment: You are correct. The only way to do that is write in your code (see`write`). You could read everything from `stdin`, then write it back without the `\n` if you want to read from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, as commented by alk, Ctrl-D did the trick for not having to press enter.